# Get all comments for each post json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, while-loop

I have a posts array that I would like to get all my comments into to show up on within my site.

Each post has a `streamitem_id`

The posts id on the streamdata table is `streamitem_id`

The comments that have been posted on a given post are on the streamdata_comments table under `comment_streamitem`*

The reason I'm struggling so much is because, I would like the comment content  array inside the posts array. But the two top queries need to be DESC by 4 and then when I use my infinite scroll the last_id is passed back and used in the second query where another 4 posts are collected and shown. So each time this happens, I would like all comment's to come with their designated posts.

I've searched for some examples as I would and try to do it myself before asking, but all I managed to really find that is close, is posts about WP, which is no good to me.

**POST QUERY WITH ARRAY**

```
    if ($last_id==0){
    $query = "SELECT *
    FROM streamdata m
    JOIN streamdata_comments t1
    WHERE 
    m.streamitem_id=t1.comment_streamitem
    AND
    t1.comment_poster=$user1_id
    GROUP BY m.streamitem_id
    ORDER BY t1.comment_id DESC LIMIT 4";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die('Error: ' .mysqli_error($mysqli));

    }else{
    $testa=$_POST['last_id'];
    $query = "SELECT *
    FROM streamdata m
    JOIN streamdata_comments t1 
    WHERE 
    m.streamitem_id=t1.comment_streamitem
    AND
    t1.comment_poster=$user1_id
    AND
    t1.comment_id < $testa
    GROUP BY m.streamitem_id
    ORDER BY t1.comment_id DESC LIMIT 4";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die('Error: ' .mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }

    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $json = array(); 

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $json[] = array(
   'streamitem_id' => $row['streamitem_id'],
   'streamitem_content' => $row['streamitem_content'],
    }
    echo json_encode(array('posts' => $json, 'last_id' => $last_id));
```

**COMMENTS QUERY AND ARRAY**

I was really unsure whether or not I had to create a separate query without DESC as this would limit the amount of comments returned if put inside the previous queries while loop!

```
    $callcomments = "SELECT *
    FROM streamdata m
    JOIN streamdata_comments t1
    WHERE 
    t1.comment_streamitem=m.streamitem_id
    AND
    t1.comment_targetuser=$user1_id
    ORDER BY t1.comment_id DESC ";
    $check1comments = mysqli_query($mysqli, $callcomments) or  die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    $comments = array();
    while($rowcomments = mysqli_fetch_array($check1comments)){
    $comments[] = array(
   'comment_id' => $rowcomments['comment_id'],
   'comment_content' => $rowcomments['comment_content'],
   );
   }
   echo json_encode(array('posts' => $comments));
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have this working. I changed the comments query to match streamitem_id from the while loop against the comment_streamiem row within my streamdata_comments table., 
I then added the below code and its array inside the posts while loop and then added `"Streamitem_comments => $streamitem_comments,`into the `$json` array.

```
    $callcomments = "SELECT * FROM streamdata_comments WHERE comment_streamitem = 
    ".$row['streamitem_id']."";
    $check1comments = mysqli_query($mysqli, $callcomments) or         
    die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $comment_num=mysqli_num_rows($check1comments);
    $commenting = array();
    while ($rowcomments = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check1comments)){
    $commentsArray = array(
   'comment_id' => $rowcomments['comment_id'],
   'comment_content' => $rowcomments['comment_content'],
   'comment_streamitem' => $rowcomments['comment_streamitem']
    );
    $commenting[] = $commentsArray;
    }
```